# Office Plugin won't show up in local desktop version of Excel - Manifest issue?

Tags: xml, excel, vue.js, office-js

I'm new to Microsoft Office Addin development, tho I've completed my first Excel Addin (yeh), with JavaScript and Vue.js.

It does completely work inside the online Office 365 Excel variant. As I'm no verified Developer or 365 Admin, I'm uploading the manifest.xml every single time to Office.com.

I am now trying to get my Addin to work inside the local Version, by following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins

The Result: Not a single addin is shown up in the dialog (.."Shared Addins"...)

I tried to solve the issue with a validation of my manifest - which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
          xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>8changed-249c-4bdf-8b4a-changed407f5</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>[Provider name]</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="myAddin" />
  <Description DefaultValue="[Workbook Add-in description]"/>

  <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://myAddin..mydomain.xxx/assets/icon-32.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://myAddin..mydomain.xxx/assets/hi-res-icon.png"/>

  <!--If you plan to submit this add-in to the Office Store, uncomment the SupportUrl element below-->
  <!--<SupportUrl DefaultValue="[Insert the URL of a page that provides support information for the app]">-->

  <!--Begin TaskPane Mode integration. This section is used if there are no VersionOverrides or if the Office client version does not support add-in commands. -->
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://myAddin..mydomain.xxx/index.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <!-- End TaskPane Mode integration.  -->

  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>some.text.io</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>myAddin..mydomain.xxx</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->


  <!-- Begin Add-in Commands Mode integration. -->
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">

    <!-- The Hosts node is required. -->
    <Hosts>
      <!-- Each host can have a different set of commands. -->
      <!-- Excel host is Workbook, Word host is Document, and PowerPoint host is Presentation. -->
      <!-- Make sure the hosts you override match the hosts declared in the top section of the manifest. -->
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <!-- Form factor. Currently only DesktopFormFactor is supported. -->
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!--"This code enables a customizable message to be displayed when the add-in is loaded successfully upon individual install."-->
          <GetStarted>
            <!-- Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
            <Title resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Title"/>

            <!-- Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
            <Description resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Description"/>

            <!-- Point to a url resource which details how the add-in should be used. -->
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <!-- Function file is a HTML page that includes the JavaScript where functions for ExecuteAction will be called.
            Think of the FunctionFile as the code behind ExecuteFunction. -->
          <!--<FunctionFile resid="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" />-->

          <!-- PrimaryCommandSurface is the main Office Ribbon. -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use OfficeTab to extend an existing Tab. Use CustomTab to create a new tab. -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <!-- Ensure you provide a unique id for the group. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your company name. -->
              <Group id="Contoso.Group1">
                <!-- Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                <Label resid="Contoso.Group1Label" />
                <!-- Icons. Required sizes 16,32,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX. -->
                <!-- Use PNG icons. All URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS. -->
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                </Icon>

                <!-- Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu". -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                    <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
                    <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                  </Icon>

                  <!-- This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane. -->
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <!-- Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane. -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <!-- You can use resources across hosts and form factors. -->
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" DefaultValue="https://myAddin..mydomain.xxx/assets/img/textengine-logo-flat.svg" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" DefaultValue="https://myAddin..mydomain.xxx/assets/img/textengine-logo-flat.svg" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" DefaultValue="https://myAddin..mydomain.xxx/assets/img/textengine-logo-flat.svg" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://myAddin..mydomain.xxx/index.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812" />
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://myAddin..mydomain.xxx/index.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <!-- ShortStrings max characters==125. -->
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="myAddin" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Group1Label" DefaultValue="myAddin" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get some Content generated!" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <!-- LongStrings max characters==250. -->
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click me to get some Content generated!" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="myAddin loaded and ready to fire some Texts!" />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
  <!-- End Add-in Commands Mode integration. -->

</OfficeApp>
```

the validation gives me following error:

```
    + validate-office-addin ./*manifest.xml
Calling validation service. This might take a moment...
-------------------------------------
Validation: Failed
Error #1: 
XML Schema Violation: Your manifest does not adhere to the current set of XML schema definitions for Office Add-in manifests. (link: https://aka.ms/add-in-manifest-schema-violation)
  - Details: The element 'OfficeApp' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1' has invalid child element 'AppDomains' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1'. List of possible elements expected: 'Dictionary' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1' as well as 'VersionOverrides' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides' as well as any element in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'.
  - Line: 41
- Column: 4
```

to following the linked guide https://aka.ms/add-in-manifest-schema-violation doesn't look like I made any mistakes.

May someone has a better knowledge of it than me or has some debugging tips?

Answer (score 1):

The order of the elements matters. (And we at Microsoft have not properly documented the required order.) I believe **AppDomains** must be between your **HighResolutionIconUrl** element and the **Hosts** element just below it. The XSD for the manifest is (barely) human readable and might help: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/tree/master/docs/overview/schemas/taskpane

Answer (score 0):

Acutally, the Answer to my Question "why did it not show up in the offline Variant of Microsoft Office Excel - even not in the 'add an Addin Page'" is:
'Offline Excel' seems to not like .svg's (not even specified inside the XML) - I must have overread this in the doc's... I digged deep into my git commits and reversed it step by step till I found that out..

This one was it:

```
  <bt:Images>
    <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" DefaultValue="https://myAddin..mydomain.xxx/assets/img/textengine-logo-flat.svg" />
    <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" DefaultValue="https://myAddin..mydomain.xxx/assets/img/textengine-logo-flat.svg" />
    <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" DefaultValue="https://myAddin..mydomain.xxx/assets/img/textengine-logo-flat.svg" />
  </bt:Images>
```

Anyway, thanks Rick, that's good to know and helps me verry much, as the Validator Service still dosn't think my Manifest is valid.. (but it tho works! :) )